# Is there a non OVA version of season 2 of Strike the Blood?

Tags: strike-the-blood

The first season of the Strike the Blood anime has 24 episodes. For the second season I found an OVA version of 8 episodes. Is there a larger regular anime series of the second season with 24 episodes or so like the first season, or is this 8 episodes OVA version all there is for the second season?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that is all there is for the 2nd season, with only 8 OVA episodes. The [MAL page](https://myanimelist.net/anime/33286/Strike_the_Blood_II) *does not include any alternative versions or episodes for the 2nd season other than those*. The 3rd season is also [similar](https://myanimelist.net/anime/37449/Strike_the_Blood_III); OVA version with 10 episodes.